# Tabulating results for quick SharePoint survey

Tags: sharepoint, graph, wss, survey

We have a one-question checkbox (multiple selection) survey in SharePoint.

When selecting "Show a graphical summary of responses" in SharePoint,  it tabulates the different combinations of responses as distinct answers as opposed to totaling the number of each option selected.

Is there a way to show the total of each option selected in the Graphical Summary view?

Comment: Can you export the results to excel and do the graphing there? Maybe via a macro or (if you're up for torture...er...I mean a challenge, maybe Excel web services?)

Comment: WSS, so no Excel web services. I'll leave this as an exercise for the business user :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using only out of the box solutions, no. I have had many users reporting "hey, look, I found a bug in your portal survey" and actually complaining about the problem you're describing here.
The only workaround I've found is to use  multiple checkbox fields instead of one multi-choice field. However, this does not look that nice.